# In Fortran, is that possible to link an integer to a procedure (a subroutine or a function)?

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I am writing a Fortran program to solve Euler Project problems. In my implementation each problem is a function, for example:

```
character(len=20) function euler_problem_0001()
    use some_external_lib
    ...
end function euler_problem_0001
```

and if I print the function I simply get the answer.

```
print *, euler_problem_0001()
```

Now I have finished quite a few problems and I find it a bit tedious to write `print *, euler_problem_xxxx()` over and over again. So my questions is: **Is there a way that I can construct a derived type that could link an integer (number of the problem) with the actual procedure?** Something like

```
type, public :: int_to_proc
    character(len=:) :: proc_name 
    procedure(proc_x), pointer :: proc_p 
end type int_to_proc
```

so that if I initialize the type with an integer,

```
call int_to_proc%init(2)
```

then the type bound procedure pointer will point to the function `euler_problem_0002()`. In this case I only have to write a loop similar to this

```
type(int_to_proc) :: prob

do i = 1, 500
    call prob%init(i)
    print *, prob%proc_p()
end do
```

instead of writing 500 lines of `print *, euler_problem_xxxx()`. Also, any work-around is also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You can use procedure pointers. Idea: 1. Define an interface for procedures that take no arguments and that return a `character(len=20)` result. 2. Define a user-defined-type with such a procedure. 3. Define an array of say type. 4. Fill the array with your results. Now, you can loop over that array and call the contained procedure.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Hi, Thx for you reply! I am trying to implement your idea but I find in step 4 I still have to make each element of the pointer array points to the corresponding procedure, like `ptr_arr(1)%proc_ptr => prob0001`, `ptr_arr(2)%proc_ptr => prob0002`, etc. Now I have to write 500 lines of pointer assignments instead of 500 lines of `print *,`, and a loop. Hmm......

Comment: There is no perfect solution :-) You can generate that code, though, to avoid the repetitiveness.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thank you. I guess a work around is to write another Fortran program that automatically generates all the pointer assignments, write them into a header file, and then include the header files in the program. In this case I still have these 500 lines but at least I don't have to write them myself.

Comment: You can even copy-paste the code in your program file or in a module subroutine. At some point, there is going to be a reference of some sort to these 500 routines :-)

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I find this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-procedure-pointers-as-derived-type-components) very useful. What it describes is very similar to your answer, except it makes the procedures into a link-list. Thank you again for your help!